# Item in top of for loop doesn't match item inside it, but it still prints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through a bit of python code and something caught my eye that doesn't make sense to me.

I have this list:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'melon', 'grape', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'persimmon', 'fruit1', 'fruit2','fruit3']


for kittens in fruits:
    print(fruit)
```

returns:

```
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
 fruit3
```

Meanwhile......

```
for fruit in fruits:
    print(num)
```

Returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-422-f672ba99a550> in <module>()
      1 for fruit in fruits:
----> 2     print(num)

NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

I wouldn't expect either to work, mostly because I assumed that python's syntax for a for loop works like:

```
for item in list:
    do something to item
```

But I'm not sure why 'fruit' is somehow recognized in the first example and returns the last item in the list.

What's going on?

Comment: `fruit` has been defined somewhere else in your code, possibly through an import

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Are you sure you are not declaring loop somewhere else?

Comment: @ic3b3rg - That was it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the first loop you posted starts executing, `fruit` is already defined. This seems to be probably because a **previous for loop** using that variable, something like:

```python
for fruit in fruits:
  # Do something
```

When that loop finishes, `fruit` doesn't dissapear and keeps alive with the last value it had

Comment: Jonathan, did this answer let you clear what is going on in the code you posted? If not, tell me what you don't understand yet

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `fruit` must have been defined elsewhere in your code and was holding the value "fruit3". In the second example, you never defined `num`, and so you were attempting to print a variable that didn't exist, thus the `NameError`.